# NSArray refuses to writetofile

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, nsarray, plist

I have an `NSArray` of objects that wont write to a file. Here is the object header:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface HSMenuItem : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSNumber *Id;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSNumber *Meal;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSNumber *DayOfTheWeek;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *Body;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *StartTime;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *EndTime;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSNumber *Seated;


- (NSString*) FriendlyMeal;
- (NSDate*) Start;
- (NSDate*) End;


@end
```

I am trying to write the array with `- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)flag` but it keeps returning `NO`. Here is the relevant code:

```
NSString* path = [self getPathForCacheFile:identifier]; //identifier is an NSString* argument for this function
BOOL b = [arrayToCache writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
MyLog(@"Saved: %@", b ? @"YES":@"NO");
```

I was searching around and some people were saying it had to do with `NSNumber`, but [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/PropertyList.html) documentation seems to say that `NSNumber` is OK to use. What is going on here?

**Edit**

I understand whats going on after reading the possible duplicate. This is indeed a duplicate. Please close.

Comment: "*identifier is an argument*" is as useful as "*getPathForCacheFile is a function*". How is it defined?

Comment: Updated. Its an NSString*.

Comment: Properties should always start with lower case letters.  Methods should never begin with `get`.